# Delete variable from RAM

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the function shown below, I want to clear the value of `x` from memory after using it.

```py
def f(x, *args):
   # do something
   y = g(x) # here i want to use x as argument and clear value of x from ram
   # do something
```

I have tried following method and checked memory usage using `memory_profiler` but nothing worked:

- `del x`
- `x = None`

---

Sample code on which I tried:

```py
%%file temp.py
import lorem

@profile
def f(x, use_none=True):
  # do something
  y = g(x)
  if use_none:
    x = None
  else:
    del x
  # do something


def g(x):
  n = len(x)
  return [lorem.paragraph() * i for i in range(n)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
  x = g([1] * 1000)
  # f(x, True)
  f(x, False)
```

`memory_profiler` command:

```py
python -m memory_profiler temp.py
```

**Result (using `None`):**

```
Filename: temp.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     3  187.387 MiB  187.387 MiB   @profile
     4                             def f(x, use_none=True):
     5                               # do something
     6  340.527 MiB  153.141 MiB     y = g(x)
     7  340.527 MiB    0.000 MiB     if use_none:
     8  340.527 MiB    0.000 MiB       x = None
     9                               else:
    10                                 del x
```

**Result (using `del`):**

```
Filename: temp.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     3  186.723 MiB  186.723 MiB   @profile
     4                             def f(x, use_none=True):
     5                               # do something
     6  338.832 MiB  152.109 MiB     y = g(x)
     7  338.832 MiB    0.000 MiB     if use_none:
     8                                 x = None
     9                               else:
    10  338.832 MiB    0.000 MiB       del x
```

**Edit**
Deleting from global and gc.collect() is not working

```
Filename: temp.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4  188.953 MiB  188.953 MiB   @profile
     5                             def f(x, use_none=True):
     6                               # do something
     7  342.352 MiB  153.398 MiB     y = g(x)
     8  342.352 MiB    0.000 MiB     if use_none:
     9                                 x = None
    10                                 globals()['x'] = None
    11                                 gc.collect()
    12                               else:
    13  342.352 MiB    0.000 MiB       del x
    14  342.352 MiB    0.000 MiB       del globals()['x']
    15  342.352 MiB    0.000 MiB       gc.collect()
```

Also, I write this code just for reference,
In my actual code, I am calling from function to another function multiple time, and sometimes call same function from inside, based on some parameter value and value of x after some operation.

After every call, I want to delete x after some operation.

Comment: Python will *garbage collect* the freed memory at some opportune point. It's not guaranteed to (and most likely won't be) recovered *immediately*. That's the nature of garbage collection.

Comment: @deceze. Except there's no memory freed here, at least not by `del` or `= None`.

Comment: Your last profiler should `del y`, which releases 50% memory. Since it  holds a reference to a list.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are using CPython (possibly other implementations too), garbage collection is triggered when the reference count for an object drops to zero. Even if the object were not garbage collected immediately, that wouldn't be the reason you are seeing your result. The reason is that you can't garbage collect objects that still have strong references to them.

`del` unbinds the name in your current namespace, decreasing the reference count by one. It does not actually delete anything. `del` is an inverse to `=`, not `__new__`.

Assigning `None`, or any other object to the name also decrements the reference count of the original binding. The only difference is that reassignment keeps the name in the namespace.

The line `x = g([1] * 1000)` creates an object in the global module namespace. You then call `f` and bind that object to the name `x` in `f`'s local namespace. At that point, there are two references to it: one in the local namesapace, and one in the global.

Your object won't disappear under normal circumstances until your module is unloaded. You can also try something like the following in `f`:

```
del x
del globals()['x']
```

Another way is to use a temporary variable to avoid assigning in the global namespace:

```
f(g([1] * 1000), False)
```

The temporary variable you pass to `f` will disappear as soon as `f` returns, even without `del`, since it isn't referenced elsewhere.

Either option might require a call to `gc.collect()` after, but shouldn't in CPython.

Comment: Very detailed. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Adding `del globals()['x']` doesn't decrease memory for me, until the function is returned. Didn't get it. Is it still referenced? Or just because gc is not triggered?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Summary of edit.



Adding del globals()['x'] doesn't decrease memory.

Also, what should I do if x if pass from some other function h instead of global environment.

Comment: Tried `del x, y` but in `f` it still references a 188 MB object somewhere, inspecting `globals` and `vars` doesn't give me anything.

Comment: It appears that the profiler prints the memory usage before the line, not after. Try adding a useless statement at the end of your function and see if the number changes there.

Comment: gc.collect() at the end is not working. I have updated the result in question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist No. The 188 MB only changes after the function is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Python garbage collection will automatically deallocate unused memory after a while. If you want to enforce `gc` immediately, the following can be tried after `del`.

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Comment: Won't help in this case. Also, in CPython garbage collection is pretty much immediate.

Comment: Can you please share some details on why it will not work in this case?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, @MadPhysicist, it was helpful! However, I could not clearly understand why `gc.collect()` will not work, if we run it after `del`. I'm asking this for my understanding and knowledge only and not to argue.

Comment: Because the garbage collector will not remove objects in active use, i.e. ones that are still being strongly referenced. The reference in the global namespace does not go away when you call `del x` in the function.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!